# How to grep for two words existing on the same line?

Tags: grep

How do I grep for lines that contain two input words on the line?  I'm looking for lines that contain both words, how do I do that? I tried pipe like this:

```
grep -c "word1" | grep -r "word2" logs
```

It just stucks after the first pipe command.

Why?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use grep to match string1 AND string2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4487328/how-to-use-grep-to-match-with-multple-strings)

Answer (score 223, accepted):

Why do you pass `-c`? That will just show the number of matches. Similarly, there is no reason to use `-r`. I suggest you read `man grep`.

To grep for 2 words existing on the same line, simply do:

```
grep "word1" FILE | grep "word2"
```

`grep "word1" FILE` will print all lines that have word1 in them from FILE, and then `grep "word2"` will print the lines that have word2 in them. Hence, if you combine these using a pipe, it will show lines containing both word1 and word2.

If you just want a count of how many lines had the 2 words on the same line, do:

```
grep "word1" FILE | grep -c "word2"
```

Also, to address your question why does it get stuck : in `grep -c "word1"`, you did not specify a file. Therefore, `grep` expects input from `stdin`, which is why it seems to hang. You can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to send an EOF (end-of-file) so that it quits.

Comment: When you're confused, the man pages are pretty much the last place you want to go for clarification. They're more confusing than randomly guessing.

Comment: @TotalFrickinRockstarFromMars: I disagree. It's true that in the beginning they might seem confusing, but once you get accustomed to the format using them is pretty straightforward. Anyway, I included it in the answer more for the "teach a man how to fish" bit, I expected the OP doesn't know them, and man pages can get pretty handy.

Comment: @houbysoft Then we'll have to agree to disagree. I've been using Linux and friends for the better part of 8 years, and I'd still rather google than use man pages.

Comment: @TotalFrickinRockstarFromMars: Well, I'm not denying the use of that. Anyway, could you point to some specific thing you find "confusing" in the grep man page, for example?

Comment: @houbysoft: what if I need to do a count

Comment: @user157195: see edit, `grep "word1" FILE | grep -c "word2"`.

Comment: "could you point to some specific thing you find 'confusing' in the grep man page?" - it's confusing why they don't include simple examples ;).  I think the broader issue is that linux utilities throw the kitchen sink at you with options, then supply single letter aliases so they can be concisely encrypted on the internet for everyone to then decypher it by googling what on earth a command does.

Comment: I have to say that the only reason that google searches are helpful is because there are good man pages and experienced people who can interpret them (or are forced to do so). @corsiKa

Comment: @geneorama Sure, but maybe the people who wrote the utlities to begin with would write better man pages and it wouldn't be an issue. The man pages are written for people who already know the tool and just need a little reminder. They're not written for people trying to figure out what they're doing.

Comment: I’m using GNU grep 3.1. The command: grep “string1” FILE | grep “string2” only finds string2.

Comment: If word1 also happened to be part of FILE's name, the result could be not what you want

Answer (score 114):

#### Prescription

One simple rewrite of the command in the question is:

```
grep "word1" logs | grep "word2"
```

The first `grep` finds lines with 'word1' from the file 'logs' and then feeds those into the second `grep` which looks for lines containing 'word2'.

However, it isn't necessary to use two commands like that.  You could use extended `grep` (`grep -E` or `egrep`):

```
grep -E 'word1.*word2|word2.*word1' logs
```

If you know that 'word1' will precede 'word2' on the line, you don't even need the alternatives and regular `grep` would do:

```
grep 'word1.*word2' logs
```

The 'one command' variants have the advantage that there is only one process running, and so the lines containing 'word1' do not have to be passed via a pipe to the second process.  How much this matters depends on how big the data file is and how many lines match 'word1'.  If the file is small, performance isn't likely to be an issue and running two commands is fine.  If the file is big but only a few lines contain 'word1', there isn't going to be much data passed on the pipe and using two command is fine.  However, if the file is huge and 'word1' occurs frequently, then you may be passing significant data down the pipe where a single command avoids that overhead.  Against that, the regex is more complex; you might need to benchmark it to find out what's best — but only if performance really matters.  If you run two commands, you should aim to select the less frequently occurring word in the first `grep` to minimize the amount of data processed by the second.

#### Diagnosis

The initial script is:

```
grep -c "word1" | grep -r "word2" logs
```

This is an odd command sequence.  The first `grep` is going to count the number of occurrences of 'word1' on its standard input, and print that number on its standard output.  Until you indicate EOF (e.g. by typing <kbd>Control-D</kbd>), it will sit there, waiting for you to type something.  The second `grep` does a recursive search for 'word2' in the files underneath directory `logs` (or, if it is a file, in the file `logs`).  Or, in my case, it will fail since there's neither a file nor a directory called `logs` where I'm running the pipeline.  Note that the second `grep` doesn't read its standard input at all, so the pipe is superfluous.

With Bash, the parent shell waits until all the processes in the pipeline have exited, so it sits around waiting for the `grep -c` to finish, which it won't do until you indicate EOF.  Hence, your code seems to get stuck.  With [Heirloom Shell](http://heirloom.sourceforge.net/), the second `grep` completes and exits, and the shell prompts again.  Now you have two processes running, the first `grep` and the shell, and they are both trying to read from the keyboard, and it is not determinate which one gets any given line of input (or any given EOF indication).

Note that even if you typed data as input to the first `grep`, you would only get any lines that contain 'word2' shown on the output.

---

Footnote:

At one time, the answer used:

```
grep -E 'word1.*word2|word2.*word1' "$@"
grep 'word1.*word2' "$@"
```

This triggered the comments below.

Comment: What is the use of "$@" can you explain. You have not mention any file name.

Comment: @PrabhatKumarSingh: Inside a shell script, `"$@"` expands to all the arguments passed to the shell script (that haven't been shifted away).  It could be a list of file names or it could be empty, in which case `grep` will read from standard input.  The original code in the question doesn't mention any file names either.  It will read from  standard input, therefore.

Comment: ok I understand what $@ means in shell script but I have not seen _script_ mentioned in your answer that's why got confused.

Comment: Plus 1 for a more efficient way that doing grep grep.

Comment: Another positive thing of this solution is that it works if both words are the same, that means it can also detect whether a word is repeated in a line. The accepted solution doesn't handle this case. +1.

Comment: If you use the `--color=auto` flag, this solution also highlights the results in a better way than when using two greps.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler When `grep 'word1.*word2'` is used can it highlight only `word1` and `word2` on the find lines?

Comment: @alper — no.  You might get the desired result with `grep ‘word1.*word2’ | grep -F -e ‘word1’ -e ‘word2’`, but I've not checked that.

Comment: When you have colored output, then this solution would color `word1,,,everything inbetween...word2`.  Is there a way to just color word1 and word2.  like when you do `grep 'word1|word2` - that is OR, but analogous  like `grep 'word1&word2` that would work?

Comment: It certainly wouldn’t be trivial to achieve that, @DenisZ.  You would probably need to run the output from this code through a colourizing `grep` looking for just the two words: `grep -E -e ‘word1|word2’`.

Comment: Thanks @JonathanLeffler I posted question and got a few solutions, but looks to be the easiest to use `--color=always`, as you suggested, and just grep word2 in pipe

Answer (score 12):

you could use awk. like this...

```
cat <yourFile> | awk '/word1/ && /word2/'
```

Order is not important. So if you have a file and...

a file named , file1 contains:

```
word1 is in this file as well as word2
word2 is in this file as well as word1
word4 is in this file as well as word1
word5 is in this file as well as word2
```

then,

```
/tmp$ cat file1| awk '/word1/ && /word2/'
```

will result in,

```
word1 is in this file as well as word2
word2 is in this file as well as word1
```

yes, awk is slower.

Comment: useless use of `cat(1)`

Comment: A single Awk is still likely to be faster than two separate `grep` processes. (But of course the extra [useless `cat`](/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat) process would more or less nullify that difference.)

Answer (score 7):

The main issue is that you haven't supplied the first grep with any input. You will need to reorder your command something like

```
grep "word1" logs | grep "word2"
```

If you want to count the occurences, then put a '-c' on the second grep.

Answer (score 5):

#### [`git grep`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-grep)

Here is the syntax using [`git grep`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/332160/21471) combining multiple patterns using *Boolean* expressions:

```
git grep -e pattern1 --and -e pattern2 --and -e pattern3
```

<sup>The above command will print lines matching all the patterns at once.</sup>

If the files aren't under version control, add `--no-index` param.

> Search files in the current directory that is not managed by Git.

Check `man git-grep` for help.

See also:

- [How to use grep to match string1 AND string2?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4487328/55075)
- [Check if all of multiple strings or regexes exist in a file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49762772/55075).
- [How to run grep with multiple AND patterns?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/55359/21471)
- For multiple patterns stored in the file, see: [Match all patterns from file at once](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/332160/21471).

Answer (score 4):

You cat try with below command

```
cat log|grep -e word1 -e word2
```

Comment: These commands search for at least one word, not for all. and the cat | is unnecessary, you can give the file as grep last argument

Comment: Probably useless use of cat?!

Answer (score -2):

Use grep:

```
grep -wE "string1|String2|...." file_name
```

Or you can use:

```
echo string | grep -wE "string1|String2|...."
```

Comment: These commands search for at least one word, not for all