# How to grep for a files with line str1 AND str2

Tags: regex, grep

I have what looked to me as a simple operation but cannot find a solution. I need to search through files in a directory with lines containing `str1` *AND* `str2`. There are several examples of `str1|str2` e.g. grep -r "`str1|str2`" . But nothing for `str1` *AND* `str2`. Can anyone provide a solution. This should be a common problem.

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6480687/grep-for-2-words-existing-on-the-same-line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
egrep 'str1.*str2|str2.*str1' FILES
```

with `egrep`. Or with positive lookahead/behind regexes. Read the manual.

Answer (score 2):

It is a common problem and here is the common solution:

```
awk '/str1/&&/str2/' file
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't ask this, but if you want files that contain both str1 and str2 but not on the same line:

```
grep str2 $(grep -l str1)
```