# How to grep -w for 2 words that might or might not occur in the same line?

Tags: grep, cpu-word, text-files

I would need the combination of the 2 commands, is there a way to just grep once? Because the file may be really big, >1gb

```
$ grep -w 'word1' infile
$ grep -w 'word2' infile
```

I don't need them on the same line like [grep for 2 words existing on the same line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6480687/grep-for-2-words-existing-on-the-same-line). I just need to avoid redundant iteration of the whole file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this:

```
grep -E -w "word1|word2" infile
```

or

```
egrep -w "word1|word2" infile
```

It will match lines matching either word1, word2 or both.

---

From man grep:

```
   -E, --extended-regexp
          Interpret PATTERN as an extended regular expression (ERE, see below).
```

#### Test

```
$ cat file
The fish [ate] the bird.
[This is some] text.
Here is a number [1001] and another [1201].
$ grep -E -w "is|number" file
[This is some] text.
Here is a number [1001] and another [1201].
```