# How to Grep Different words in Different lines in Linux

Tags: linux, shell, unix, grep

I am trying to monitor a log using `tail -f` command and when ever I come across two different words in different lines on same log, need to capture those and send a email notification:

For example: `cat example.txt`:

```
<event> 12345 </event>
<Description> Exception on file transfer for user ABC </Description>
```

I need to monitor for event '12345' having 'Exception' for user 'ABC'.

When I do `tail -F example.txt | egrep "12345|Exception|ABC"` This 
command prints if it sees any one of Grep keyword. Instead it needs to print only if it comes across all keywords in grep.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find patterns across multiple lines using grep?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2686147/how-to-find-patterns-across-multiple-lines-using-grep)

Comment: Also see [How to use grep to match string1 AND string2?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4487328/608639) and [How to grep for two words existing on the same line?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6480687/608639)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
tail -f example.txt | egrep --line-buffered  "Exception.*ABC" -B 1 | egrep -v Description
```

- "Exception.*ABC"  search for lines having Exception AND ABC
- "-B 1"  is to have previous line (the event)
- "--line-buffered" is to turn grep buffering mode (else the second egrep won't process)
- "| egrep -v Description"  finally removes the Description line (since you just want the event)

you will end up having

```
    <event> 12345 </event>
```

Play with each parameter to see the difference

regards

Comment: Thank You @altagir. This helped