# Grep with two ordered strings (like logical AND in regex)

Tags: regex, grep

I am trying to grep a file for lines with two strings, so *string1* logical_**AND** *string2*.

Example line to `grep` for:

```
The quick brown fox and the cat
```

I want to `grep` out that line by matching for *"quick"* and *"the cat"*, note the space between *"the"* and *"cat"*. That is what is throwing me off.

```
grep .*quick.*cat myfile
```

This works fine but I want to grep for *"the cat"* and;

```
grep .*quick.*the cat myfile
```

Obviously doesn't work because of the space. I don't understand how I can encompass *"the cat"* with the space in it?

Comment: I'm only guessing here, but try to encompass your expression with a pair of parenthesis (`"expression"`), or delimiters (`/expression/`)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use grep to match string1 AND string2?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4487328/608639)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try putting quotes around the string you are searching for i.e.

```
grep ".*quick.*the cat" myfile
```

Comment: Oh man, I wouldn't have posted this question without trying that, as it's so blindingly obvious, and I'm sure I did. I must have made a typo, still thanks anyway for pointing out I'm an idiot :)

Comment: No prob :) I've been through that myself - the combinations of the quotes plus the regex confuses even the experienced.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
grep ".*quick.*the cat" myfile
```