# Search with grep for two expressions at once

Tags: bash, grep

This is basic but I am unable to google it. Can I use on invokation of grep to do

```
grep expr1 | grep expr2
```

so that it prints lines including both expr1 and expr2?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use grep to match string1 AND string2?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4487328/608639)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Try this:

`grep 'expr1.*expr2\|expr2.*expr1'`

That's a little more complicated than it needs to be if you know that "expr2" will always come after "expr1".  In that case, you could simplify it to:

`grep 'expr1.*expr2'`

Comment: Rather than have a lot of identical questions - above worked for me except I did:  ` sudo grep -E -rnw '/var/log/' -e 'Out of memory.*Jan 17|Jan 17.*Out of memory'` - without the backslash. Linux Mint 18.3, GNU bash 4.3.48

Answer (score 49):

You can provide several expressions to search for with several [-e flags](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html#Matching-Control). See also [this post](http://liquidat.wordpress.com/2008/10/08/short-tip-grep-with-more-than-one-expression/).

i.e.

> grep -e expr1 -e expr2

Comment: @sup: in GNU grep 2.16 the suggested command line searches both expressions

Comment: I am running GNU GREP 2.25 and running `grep --version |grep -e is -e software` does not seem to search for lines containing both exrpresions, but it searches for lines containing either expresion.

Answer (score 3):

What you have should work.

The following is an alternative way to achieve the same effect:

```
grep -E 'expr1.*expr2|expr2.*expr1'
```

Comment: I know it works:-). I was just tired of invoking grep two times all over. But it seems it is quicker to just write grep twice then to type this in. Unfortunately, I often do not know the order of expressions. I was hoping for something like `grep (expr1ANDexpr2)` :-). By the way, is this even faster in a sript than calling grep twice?

Answer (score 1):

Actually your own suggestion is nearly correct if you want to get the lines that contain both expressions. Use:

```
grep expr1 somefile | grep expr2
```

Comment: Oh, I use normally `cat somefile | grep expr1 | grep expr2`, but I think it is not important which software I use to pipe the stuff:-).

Comment: This will make an "and" instead of the "or" operation, won't it?

Comment: You could also use `grep < somefile expr1 | grep expr2`, since we're playing the "how many ways can I do the same thing" game.

Comment: @RicardPérezdelCampo The OP wants "and".