# Using grep to print one of the listed strings but print all of them if more than one exists

Tags: regex, terminal, grep, osx-yosemite

I have three strings that I search for within a file. To find the lines with either one of them, I use

```
grep 'string1\|string2\|string3' file
```

I want to print out only the matched strings within each line, using the `-o` flag. But in this case if two of the strings are present in the line, only one of them shows up. Is there a way to get something like `string1` and/or `string2` etc. without having to list 6 cases with and and or using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4487328/using-grep-to-match-multiple-strings).

Note that I am using OS X Yosemite.

Expected output:

```
string1
string1 string2
string3
string1 string3
string3
```

etc.

Comment: Can you include a sample input and expected output?

Comment: @hwnd it prints only one of those strings if more than one exists within a line.

Comment: If your `grep` has option `-n` to show matching line numbers: use `-n -o` and post-process `grep`'s output with awk. I'm no awk specialist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to print the line numbers, The records which are repeated
will not have the line numbers. Then just join the line with post processing.

```
grep -Eon 'string1|string2|string3' txt 

1:string1
2:string2
string3
3:string3
4:string1
string2
```

In above case `2:string2` and `string3` can be joined to form  `string2 string3`

Complete command on Mac OS

```
 grep -Eon 'string1|string2|string3' txt | tr  '\n' ' ' 
 | sed -E 's/ [0-9]:/:/g' | tr ':' '\n'
```

the last `tr` & `sed` command can be replaced with single `sed` command. but somehow new line character not working on Mac sed.

The output will be similar to this

```
string1
string2 string3
string3
string1 string2 string3
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an extra trailing `\|` in the end, try

```
grep -o 'string1\|string2\|string3' file
string1
string1
string2
string3
string1
string3
string3
```

---

**EDIT:** You can use this `grep` with gnu-awk:

```
grep -no 'string1\|string2\|string3' file | awk -v RS='[0-9]+:' 'NR>1{
      gsub(/\n/, "\t"); print}'
```

Comment: That's a typo I made while I was writing the question. So this command prints the second occurrence in a new line? How can I keep them together?

Comment: To keep them together you can just omit `-o` flag but it will print full line