# Grep for multiple words in log files

Tags: regex, linux, grep

I have file which has contents like:

```
--------------------------------
service=serviceX
time=100ms
PARAMS={"data"=>"{\"id\":1,\"items\":[{\"quantity\":1,\"name\":\"itemName1\"
        ,\"quantity\":2,\"name\":\"itemName2\"}]}
------------------------------------------------
  --------------------------------
service=serviceX
time=200ms
PARAMS={"data"=>"{\"id\":2,\"items\":[{\"quantity\":2,\"name\":\"itemName3\"
        ,\"quantity\":2,\"name\":\"itemName4\"}]}
------------------------------------------------
  --------------------------------
service=serviceX
time=300ms
PARAMS={"data"=>"{\"id\":3,\"items\":[{\"quantity\":1,\"name\":\"itemName5\"
        ,\"quantity\":2,\"name\":\"itemName6\"}]}
------------------------------------------------
```

I am trying to find all the items in listed in the file.
My query looks like

```
grep -o  'name\\":\\"[^\\]*\\"' | tr -d '\\"'
```

and the output is

```
name:itemName1
name:itemName2
name:itemName3
name:itemName4
name:itemName5
name:itemName6
```

I want the output like:

```
id:1
name:itemName1
name:itemName2
id:2
name:itemName3
name:itemName4
id:3 
name:itemName5
name:itemName6
```

I am new to linux and not sure how to grep for multiple words in a single query.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use grep to match multiple strings?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4487328/how-to-use-grep-to-match-multiple-strings)

Answer (score 1):

Or use [alternation metacharacter](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html):

```
grep -oP 'name\\":\\"[^\\]*\\|id\\":[^,]*' | tr -d '\\"'
                              ↑
          |__________________| |____________|
             look for this   or    that
```