# How to grep two patters in different lines of one file, recursively in subfolders?

Tags: grep

```
./folder1/file1:3.100 ... 
./folder1/file1: 3.99.5

./folder1/file2:... 
./folder1/file2: 3.100

./folder1/file3:3.99.5 
./folder1/file3: ...

./folder2/file1:3.99.5 
./folder2/file1: ...

./folder2/file2:3.100 ... 
./folder2/file2: 3.99.5

./folder2/file3:...
./folder2/file3: 3.100
```

Please explain, how to grep patterns "**3.100**" AND "**3.99.5**" in files in all subfolders, to get list of matched files:

```
folder1/file1
folder2/file2
```

Thanks in advance !:)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use grep to match multiple strings in the same line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4487328/how-to-use-grep-to-match-multiple-strings-in-the-same-line)

Comment: the question is not clear whether the search terms are in single line or multiple lines, the duplicate has solutions for both cases

Comment: I meant to match files with BOTH patterns only... that is why I wrote folder1/file1 and folder2/file2 as example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grep all files, print only names of matching files and rescan with `xargs grep`:

```
grep '3\.100' * -r -l  | xargs -d '\n' grep -l '3\.99\.5'
```

Comment: Oh, I see you've edited your question to make the files mutli-line. My answer is no longer valid.

Comment: Yeah, I did it to cut off "simple grep | grep" answer :) The main Q: is to grep those 3.100 and 3.99.5 args inside .mp3 files, that is why I modified my question:)

Comment: Looks like there is a (small?) problem with files those have space in their filenames... Could you, please, modify your method to operate files with spaces?

Comment: Sorry, you are right. I added the `-d '\n'` directive as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16758525/make-xargs-handle-filenames-that-contain-spaces). Try it now.

Comment: Sorry for delay - Yes, this updated algo is working as I wanted - THANK YOU very much !!:) And.. heck, I have 14 reputation points so I cannot vote for your great answer, sorry again! :/

Comment: Ppl, how can I close this Q: as solved one? Thanks in advance !:)

Comment: You should [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Also see [this example](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)

Comment: BTW, "*" should be replaced with "." - it gives normal mode to scan current folder with subfolders:)