# How to match patterns that need to satisfy multiple requirements using regular expressions?

Tags: regex, grep

I'm having problems in `egrep` trying to figure out a AND like operator for regular expression pattern matching, I need to match all the strings that must satisfy multiple conditions in a given list of strings, here are some questions I'm having problems with

1) Find the set of words that contain two consecutive
   e's, AND also contains at least two i's ( `ieei` is valid )

2) Find the set of words that are at least 5 characters long AND
   do not contain any vowels

I tried using lookaheads `(?=.*?ee)(?=.*?i.*i)` but it doesn't work, what am I missing here?

Comment: if you have `GNU grep`, then try using `grep -P <your regex>` ... by default, grep supports only BRE/ERE and those do not have lookarounds, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119905/why-does-my-regular-expression-work-in-x-but-not-in-y

Comment: another option is to use grep multiple times, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4487328/how-to-use-grep-to-match-string1-and-string2

Comment: I've been using "egrep -e" from the UNIX egrep utility and what you said seems to be the case, is there a way to check for multiple requirements using BRE/ERE without using multiple lines?

Answer (score 0):

As mentionned by [Sundeep](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4082052/) your `grep` implementation might support PCRE through the use of the `-P` flag, in which case the following would work :

```
grep -P '(?=.*?ee)(?=.*?i.*i)'
```

Otherwise, you can use the following ERE pattern instead :

```
[^ ]*(i[^ ]*ee[^ ]*i|i[^ ]*i[^ ]*ee|ee[^ ]*i[^ ]*i)[^ ]*
```

It matches words that conform to one of those 3 patterns :

- the word contains an i followed by two consecutive e followed by another i
- the word contains an i followed by another i followed by two consecutive e
- the word contains two consecutive e followed by an i followed by another i

Comment: Thankyou the ERE pattern works, but i'm still stuck at the 2nd question cause it's seems impractical to list out all the patterns which have atleast 5 letters and don not contain any vowels

Comment: @Laventio_19 research negated character classes. I use them in my ERE regex to avoid matching more than a word : I use a character class that matches any character but a space, `[^ ]`

Comment: I'm aware "....." and "[^aeiou] " would give me the answer im looking for but im having problems combining those two expressions into a single expression

Comment: @Laventio_19 you shouldn't use `.` as it might match vowels. You could use multiple occurences of `[^aeiou]`, but you'd better use a quantifier such as `{5,}` "5 of more occurences of the previous token". You might also need to use `\b` word-boundaries to make sure you match the whole word. Consider following a quick regex tuto, given the questions' level you should already be familiar with quantifiers