# Combine multiple grep regular expression into one command

Tags: grep

Consider this input file:

```
bam/pfg413T.GRCh38DH.target.bai
bam/pfg413T.GRCh38DH.target.bam
bam/pfg413T.GRCh38DH.target.bam
bam/pfg416G.GRCh38DH.target.bai
bam/pfg416G.GRCh38DH.target.bam
```

How can I combine the following multiple `grep -E` into one `grep -E` pipe ?

`readlink -f exomesinglesample_out/bam/pfg* | grep -E 'pfg[0-9]*G' | grep -E 'bam$'`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Match two strings in one line with grep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4487328/match-two-strings-in-one-line-with-grep)

Comment: ok cool but I thought about one regular expression block only. thanks

Comment: `grep 'pfg[0-9]*G.*bam$'`?