# PCL - Papers/algorithms implemented

Tags: 3d, point-cloud-library

Is there any systematic way to find out which paper is implemented for PCL library functions?
e.g. which paper was implemented for the registration functions?

I had the same question about OpenCV, but apparently for OpenCV one relies just on the documentation, where sometimes the corresponding paper is mentioned e.g. [here](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html?highlight=distance%20transform#void%20distanceTransform%28InputArray%20src,%20OutputArray%20dst,%20OutputArray%20labels,%20int%20distanceType,%20int%20maskSize,%20int%20labelType%29)

Thanks!

Comment: The tag wiki for [tag:pcl] is about the HP printer driver technology, which I don't believe has much basis in academic work. You might want to provide some context as to which PCL you mean, or a more appropriate tag.

Comment: didn't notice, thanks for the comment @millimoose, it's fixed now ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to check the [documentation](http://docs.pointclouds.org/1.6.0/classpcl_1_1_p_p_f_registration.html) or the comments in the source code. For example, the link I've reported mentions this paper used in the registration process:

> Please refer to the following publication for more details: B. Drost, M. Ulrich, N. Navab, S. Ilic Model Globally, Match Locally: Efficient and Robust 3D Object Recognition 2010 IEEE Conference on Computer Vision and Pattern Recognition (CVPR) 13-18 June 2010, San Francisco, CA

You could try looking for "IEEE" or "ACM" inside the source code through [grep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4275900/grep-search-all-files-in-directory-for-string1-and-string2) or some similar utility. Hope this helps!