# How to combine two search words with "grep" (AND)

Tags: linux, grep

With grep, I can find a word within 50 files in a local folder, i.e.:

```
grep -i "hello" *.html
```

But how can I find files that contain TWO words? Example: I would like to find all files, that contain Word "hello" AND word "peter". How can I combine two grep's?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Grep Search all files in directory for string1 AND string2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4275900/grep-search-all-files-in-directory-for-string1-and-string2)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To see the files containing both words (possibly on different lines), use `-l` and `xargs`:

```
grep -il "hello" *.html | xargs grep -il "peter"
```

**Edit**

If your files have spaces in their names, then we need to be a little more careful.  For that we can use special options to `grep` and `xargs`:

```
grep -ilZ "hello" *.html | xargs -0 grep -il "peter"
```

Comment: Oh - I've wrote something wrong. Especially your 2nd line is extremely helpful. Thanks a lot and sorry for confusion.

Answer (score 0):

```
egrep -irl "hello" * |egrep -irl "peter" \`cat -`
```

This will search recursively in all subfolders and will match regex within the quotes

Comment: Does not work. One file should have been found. But I just get "File or path not found".