# Finding consecutive words with grep

Tags: grep

I have checked this topic to find two words in a text file: [How to combine two search words with "grep" (AND)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21209279/how-to-combine-two-search-words-with-grep-and)

But now I'm trying to know if it's possible to check when they are consecutive in the file. For instance:

grep -ilZ "not" file.txt | xargs -0 grep -il "sure"

In file.txt I have "I am not sure".

How could I do?

Thank you so much.

Comment: Please add sample input and your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just `grep -il "not sure" file.txt` would solve your problem.

Comment: I don't know what the hell happened before but now it worked, really thank you so much.