# Finding multiple strings in directory using linux commends

Tags: linux

If I have two strings, for example "class" and "btn", what is the linux command that would allow me to search for these two strings in the entire directory.

To be more specific, lets say I have directory that contains few folders with bunch of .php files. My goal is to be able to search throughout those .php files so that it prints out only files that contain "class" and "btn" in one line. Hopefully this clarifies things better.

Thanks,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Grep Search all files in directory for string1 AND string2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4275900/grep-search-all-files-in-directory-for-string1-and-string2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I normally use the following to search for strings inside my source codes. It searches for string and shows the exact line number where that text appears. Very helpful for searching string in source code files. You can always pipes the output to another grep and filter outputs.

`grep -rn "text_to_search" directory_name/`

example:

```
$ grep -rn "angular" menuapp
$ grep -rn "angular" menuapp | grep some_other_string
```

output would be:

```
menuapp/public/javascripts/angular.min.js:251://# sourceMappingURL=angular.min.js.map
menuapp/public/javascripts/app.js:1:var app = angular.module("menuApp", []);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -r /path/to/directory 'class|btn'
```

`grep` is used to search a string in a file. With the `-r` flag, it searches recursively all files in a directory.

Answer (score 0):

Or, alternatively using the `find` command to "identify" the files to be searched instead of using `grep` in recursive mode:

```
find /path/to/your/directory -type f -exec grep "text_to_search" {} \+;
```